# Showing Form Results On The Same PHP Page

Tags: php, qr-code

I have a form that calls for a QR Code off Google. The user puts in a website and then they are directed to the results page, with the QR Code. I was wondering if there was a way to make the QR Code appear on the same page? I've tried putting the Google script onto the same page but it doesn't seem to work. Code as followed:

```
<form method="post" action="qr-creation.php">
<input type="text" name="contractno"/>
<input type="submit" value="Get QR Code"/>
```

This is the Google Code:

```
<?
$urlToEncode="$short";
generateQRwithGoogle($urlToEncode);
function generateQRwithGoogle($url,$widthHeight ='500',$EC_level='L',$margin='0') {
    $url = urlencode($url); 
    echo '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs='.$widthHeight.
'x'.$widthHeight.'&cht=qr&chld='.$EC_level.'|'.$margin.
'&chl='.$url.'" alt="QR code" widthHeight="'.$widthHeight.
'" widthHeight="'.$widthHeight.'"/>';
}
?>
```

I've never really delved into AJAX so any simple help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is "the Google script" and what exactly does "doesn't seem to work" mean? In general: yes, it's perfectly possible to do it all on the same page.

Comment: Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Please see edit. I'm looking at the basics of AJAX now, but I'm not really sure how to implement.

Comment: And what is stopping you from using that code on the same page as the form?

Comment: I don't know how to action the form and make the QR Code appear on the same page. I've always sent the PHP form to a different page after it's been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

First, have the form submit to itself/same page:

```
<form method="post" action="samefile.php">
```

Then, in that same page, check if you got a POST request and if so, execute your code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['contractno'])) {
    // output QR code here
}
```

Comment: This just seems to be refreshing the page. The code is there but it's as if the variables are being wiped.

Comment: My bad, you don't have an input field with `name="submit"`. Updated.

Comment: I should have spotted that myself. Lazy looking by me. Thanks Dude.

Comment: Still no luck. If it's empty, won't that mean there is no link to put into the QR Code anyway?

Comment: if ! (empty($_POST['contractno'])) { ?

Comment: Still no luck. Strange. This is the code: 
<?php if (!empty($_POST['contractno'])) {
    
   $urlToEncode="$short";
generateQRwithGoogle($urlToEncode);
function generateQRwithGoogle($url,$widthHeight ='500',$EC_level='L',$margin='0') {
    $url = urlencode($url); 
    echo '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs='.$widthHeight.
'x'.$widthHeight.'&cht=qr&chld='.$EC_level.'|'.$margin.
'&chl='.$url.'" alt="QR code" widthHeight="'.$widthHeight.
'" widthHeight="'.$widthHeight.'"/>';
}
} ?>

Comment: And where is `$short` coming from...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13779/discussion-between-itsjoeturner-and-deceze)